# Auto incrementing number in PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

This is the beginning of a php for loop.  I would like to edit it so that 'INSERT NUMBER HERE' gets replaced with an incrementing number.  Ie. first loop it would be 1, then 2, then 3 etc.

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <div style="float: left; font-size: 120px;height:50px;padding-top:50px; color:#ccc">INSERT NUMBER HERE</div>
    <div class="listing-item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<?php 
$n = 0;
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): 
$n++;
?>
<div style="float: left; font-size: 120px;height:50px;padding-top:50px; color:#ccc"><?php echo $n; ?>
</div>
<div class="listing-item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `array_keys()` to get an indexed array from an associative array, at which point `foreach` will yield the index as the new key, and the old key as the new value. Indexing the old array with the new value will give you the old value, and the new key will be a counter for elements in the array.